# Fast switch keyboard layout in Ubuntu (10.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have 3 keyboard layouts in use. English, Arabic and Hebrew.  To switch from English to Hebrew for example, I have to hit alt-shift twice  (English -> Arabic -> Hebrew). I wonder if I can set-up something like  [ctrl]-[shift]-1 to immediately switch to English, [ctrl]-[shift]-2 for Arabic and [ctrl]-[shift]-3 for Hebrew or something similar.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `setxkbmap` with `xbindkeys`.
Example of `.xbindkeysrc`:

```
#Switch to english
"setxkbmap us"
   0x4 + c:10
Control + 1 

#Switch to russian
"setxkbmap ru"
   m:0x4 + c:11
Control + 2 

#Switch to japanese
"setxkbmap jp"
   m:0x4 + c:12
Control + 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a generic command shortcut to the `setxkbmap` command with the given layout as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good direction, but it doesn't do exactly what I wanted it to do. Looks like it's somehow "destructive". It doesn't play nice with the keyboard layout indicator.. Maybe I need to tweak it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Under `Layout Options` there's a section to choose keys to change the layout. This sequence will rotate the layouts though, not go to a specific one.

Answer (score 0):

this seems like an old post, but at least in kubuntu 14.04 you can set shortcuts for each layout

[image: example of setting english, hebrew and arabic with keyboard shortcuts]